# Context misses relationships data, until having a query to the table relationships

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Database with complete required data and the table `reviewer` has relationships one with many to `review`  I had (1) and (2) ways code to get the reviewer by Id (I use .net api and this was the result in swagger.)

(1)

```
var reviewer =  _context.Reviewers.Where(r => r.Id == id).Include(e => e.Reviews).FirstOrDefault(); 
return Ok(reviewer);
```

The result was

```
{   "id": 1,   "firstName": "Teddy",   "lastName": "Smith",   "reviews": null }
```

(2)

```
var reviewer =  _context.Reviewers.Where(r => r.Id == id).Include(e => e.Reviews).FirstOrDefault();
var x = _context.Reviews.ToList();
return Ok(reviewer);
```

The result was

```
{"id": 1,"firstName": "Teddy","lastName": "Smith","reviews": [{"id": 1,"title": "Pikachu","text": "Pickahu is the best pokemon, because it is electric","rating": 5,"reviewer": null,"pokemon": null}]}
```

The ways I get `reviewer` were same but the result was different. In the code (2) I just run a query to reviews

Why I didn't get the reviews in the code (1)? How can I fix it?


This is model

```
namespace i1_start.Models
{
    public class Reviewer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Review> Reviews {get; set;}
    }
}
```

```
namespace i1_start.Models
{
    public class Review
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public Reviewer Reviewer { get; set; }
        public Pokemon Pokemon { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your model like? How you define the relationship ?

Comment: Ok, I will edit my question

Comment: @QingGuo I have been add the model

Comment: (2) makes no sense, (1) should be getting the data you need. You can verify that by putting breakpoint and looking at the `reviewer` variable in the debugger. Do not rely on what you see as a json serialized output. You data model has "circular" references which are handled perfectly by EF, but not the json and similar serializers. See [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/serialization) topic in the official EF Core docs.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have been putted breakpoint and the result is as same as my example in my topic. The filed `reviews` in `var reviewer =  _context.Reviewers.Where(r => r.Id == id).Include(e => e.Reviews).FirstOrDefault(); 
`only not null until I run a query to review `var x = _context.Reviews.ToList();
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong library. Use `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`  instead `using System.Data.Entity`.

Both libraries have `.Include()` and they can be confused.

Comment: I use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and I can get the  review by your code 1: 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFvwO.png

Comment: @QingGuo You had been got it, look at your Img. The count of reviews is 1, that mean reviews has data

Comment: @QingGuo Did you really rebuild my error? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I create an asp.net core api project, use your model and use the [scaffolding tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-movie-pages) to produce Create, Read, Update, and Delete (CRUD) pages for the  model. You can refer to it.